# How can I control a Rapsberry pi from a flutter mobile app?

Tags: flutter, mobile, raspberry-pi, vnc, vnc-viewer

I am trying to create an app that can control a Raspberry Pi remotely, opening apps like if it was the mouse. I know about SSH, but I don't want the user to write command lines. I was wondering if I could create something like "VNC Viewer" (Which I don't think it could be very easy) inside my flutter app or at least open "VNC Viewer" inside my app and pass some parameters to connect directly.

Is there anything like that that could be done?

I would appreciate any guidance because I only have the idea.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if anyone has this problem I solved it using a "WebView" in flutter and x11vnc together with "NoVNC" in the Raspberry.
The WebView opens the webserver site (from NoVNC) and then I can control the Raspberry remotedly. Thanks for the "Deep links" idea, but NoVNC solved it!

I tried the example from the link and it works.

[Example of NoVNC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoObpLPqlR0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using deep links or universal links to open the actual VNC Viewer app. They might even have an api which allows you to open VNC Viewer and then do something by building a special link.

I know that you can do it in iOS/Android, but I am not sure it works using flutter. Might be something that only works natively.

Comment: Thank you! I'll investigate that. I saw there is a plugin for Deep Links in flutter bu I'll check some examples first.