# Vnc viewer for flutter for x0vnc

Tags: flutter, dart, vnc, vnc-viewer

I'm developing a flutter app to run on mobile and web, which has one functionality to create a VNC viewer to view [x0vnc](https://tigervnc.org/doc/x0vncserver.html) server started on an ubuntu machine.

I'm not able to find any VNC viewer for flutter, does such thing exist?

I could find an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64298974/6531633, but this is in Spanish and it involves a js librariy.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem recently and my solution was to just create a package for it. So here are `dart_rfb`, the protocol implementation in Dart, and `flutter_rfb`, the Flutter side of it. Feel free to check it out and contribute if you want!

https://pub.dev/packages/dart_rfb

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rfb